# Creating a custom .config file in asp.net

Tags: web-config

Is there a way I can create a blah.config file in asp.net, and access the name/value pairs of nodes the same way you access items in  in a regular web.config file?

(the idea is to not have to write any custom code for this).

Answer (score 11):

Chris shows one way to "externalize" part of your configuration. That works fine for certain scenarios. If you need more, you'll need to dig in a bit deeper.

For that, you should definitely check out Jon Rista's three-part series on .NET 2.0 configuration up on CodeProject.

- [Unraveling the mysteries of .NET 2.0 configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration.aspx)
- [Decoding the mysteries of .NET 2.0 configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration2.aspx)
- [Cracking the mysteries of .NET 2.0 configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration3.aspx)

Highly recommended, well written and extremely helpful! He shows how to create and use custom configuration sections, and goes on to explain how to use your own `blah.config` instead of or in addition to standard .NET config files.

Marc

Comment: +1 to you, @marc_s!  Via your three well-chosen links, you conveyed a *lot* of useful information in a concise post!

Answer (score 4):

Use the "file" attribute of the appSettings block, like so:

```
<appSettings file="user.config">
    <add key="Test1" value="Generic1" />
    <add key="Test2" value="Generic2" />
</appSettings>
```

Further explanation available [here](http://diablopup.blogspot.com/2007/07/file-attribute-in-webconfig.html).