# Is it possible to configure a .NET application to use a different config file without specifically adopting the source code to support such a need?

Tags: .net, configuration, app-config, configuration-files

I have a .NET application. Its source code performs no config file manipulations. I am wondering whether there is a way to instruct the CLR to bind the app to another config file. A command line switch is perfect, but as far as I know no such thing exists.

A registry change could be a solution, as long as it is consulted only during the application start, because I wish to run two instances of the app with different config files. So, if the registry is consulted during the app lifetime - no good.

Anyway, there could be other options. Still, I am unaware of any.

Anyone?

Thanks.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837133/creating-a-custom-config-file-in-asp-net While it might not be exactly the answer to your question both marc and chris's answers could give you some ideas in the right direction

Comment: Nope. While configuration framework walkthrough was very interesting I am interested in something completely different.

Answer (score 1):

Make a loader exe which does 2 following things:

1. Reloads custom `app.config` file as shown here: [Change default app.config at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150644/change-default-app-config-at-runtime/6151688#6151688)
2. Uses `Assembly.Load()` + invokes the `assembly.EntryPoint`
3. Or, even better, create a new `AppDomain`, use `domain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_PATH", your_path)` + `domain.ExecuteAssembly(your_file_name)`.

Other gotchas you're may run into:

- COM Apartment of the new thread
- Message loops already running
- WPF dispatchers already created
- possibly more :) Please post any exceptions/misbehaviours. I just don't have the code at hand right now to test, but did it before a couple of times.