# Config files in .Net 3.5 +

Tags: c#, .net, configuration-files

I need to make use of a config file as often one does. In particular I am currently using the 'ChannelFactory' and just specifying an endpoint name. This works fine at the moment but the problem is it uses appname.exe.config and the application I am using makes DDE/etc calls to other applications that also use connections using ChannelFactory.

The problem is therefore each DDE'd application would require its own appname.exe.config unless I centralise it which is what I want to do.

There doesn't appear to be alot of advise on config files out there. Ideally I want to be able able to tell the framework where my config file is so that I can continue to use the ChannelFactory(string) call as is. But I realise this is probably unlikely and I see need to manually extract some sections and build up the endpoint or some such.

Does anyone have any advise?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the config file to be used during runtime and thus use a centralized app.config. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150644/change-default-app-config-at-runtime/6151688#6151688) for more info.

Comment: Thank you, I can confirm this is the daddy.