# Change the Default AppConfig at runtime with custom config sections

Tags: c#, configuration, app-config

I essentially am in charge of a DLL for my project that uses lots of external resources.  I want to have a config file for my project named infrastructure.config that clients projects can copy in their project without having to cut and paste into their own app or web configs.  I tried the following suggestion at:

[Change default app.config at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150644/change-default-app-config-at-runtime?answertab=active#tab-top)

That solution worked well until I tried with Log4Net which utilizes a custom section.  I received an unknown configuration section when I tried to use the code in the above mentioned link.  When I use the same configuration file without the above mentioned code it works fine.  Interestingly enough, it blew up when I was trying to use TransactionScope.  So some combination of using TransactionScope and having configurationSections in my config made it fail.  Any suggestions?

I want each client app or web site to have their own config for its own values while my infrsatucture.dll should be able to have a combination of its own values, custom SOAP Bindings and Log4Net.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like what [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) is good for solving.

I would highly suggest that instead of creating an application/dll that relies on a config file (app settings or sections), that your interface expose what it needs to do it's work.  These can be external class/interfaces exposed by other DLLs (log4net) or you can create your own and allow other developers to derive concrete classes based on your required abstract/interfaces classes.

Comment: That is essentially what is happening in reverse.  The DLL which I am working on Infrasdtructure.dll is implementing Interfaces specified by a Core DLL.  One of those interfaces is for logging.  I am trying to avoid the practice of having each client copy configuration settings that are specific to the infrastructure.dll over to their config files. I was hoping that we could avoid that.  Now if my DLL was a separate running process such as a web service this would not be an issue.  I would just have my own config.  However, on this project the architect wants to just use plain old DLL's.