# My config file for dll or why cannot parse Section..?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration-files

I encountered a problem that I have no way to parse a document standard configurations.

For example:

```
private string GetConfigKey(string param)
        {
            Configuration dllConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(this.GetType().Assembly.Location);
            AppSettingsSection dllConfigAppSettings = (AppSettingsSection)dllConfig.GetSection("appSettings");
            return dllConfigAppSettings.Settings[param].Value;
        }
```

As a result, I get the settings from the file in a form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="host" value="mail.ololo.by"/>
  </appSettings>
  <configSections>
      <section name="provideConfig" type="System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler"/>
      <section name="provideMailStatus" type="System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler" />
  </configSections>
 <provideConfig>
     <add key="post@gate.ololo.by" value="Mail Subject 1"/>
     <add key="guga@gate.ololo.by" value="Mail Subject 2"/>
 </provideConfig>
  <provideMailStatus>
    <add key="status1" value="send"/>
    <add key="status2" value="draft"/>
    <add key="status2" value="other"/>
  </provideMailStatus>
</configuration>
```

but

```
Hashtable hashtable =
                (Hashtable)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("provideConfig");
 foreach (DictionaryEntry dictionaryEntry in hashtable)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dictionaryEntry.Key+" "+dictionaryEntry.Value);
            }
```

but that's unfortunately a configSections have a problem. I can not seem to get it.
MB, I go in the wrong direction?

P.S. Config file cannot be named `"app.config"` - only project dll name

Answer (score 2):

Config file should be named as executable file name and ".config". Even this executable file uses this dll-file.
For example: ConSoleApplication.exe uses MyLibrary.dll. Then config file must be named ConSoleApplication.exe.config

If You need some other name for config file read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150644/change-default-app-config-at-runtime/6151688#6151688)

Comment: I have same problem in block "section" into part are getting some configuration into file. 
I cannot parse ".config" file and take struct my section in file. I cannot get Dictionary keys and value. That is my general problems.
Config file name for me, i think, no special role played

Comment: If You haven't problem with access to file. You could use XmlSerializer for deserialize this file. But in this case i sugest to You store <provideConfig> and <provideMailStatus> in separate xml file.

Comment: WHY? I haven't any problem with access file. I have same problem with getting section.

Comment: I think, I must create "Class" are inherited by ConfigurationSection, isn't it?

Comment: I guess You need [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: yep, that was my problem, but I understood and made differently. I Parsed as XML document. LInk url i cannot insert , because I forgot where I found it. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all, I coped with the problem.
I can tell if someone will be interested.

[Configuration Section Designer Codeplex](http://csd.codeplex.com/)

[.NET Configuration Code Generator](http://nconfiggen.codeplex.com/)

Best regards, yauhen.