# Calling a DLL with reflection and configuration dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection, dll, configuration

I have a service that calls methods in other libraries through reflection. However, some of these libraries have external dependencies such as app.config files that it sometimes uses to perform its work.

Is there any best practise on how to do this, or any libraries that can help with this kind of situation?

For example: if my service should call external dll on method foo(), foo() then uses app.config to get a list of strings, but crashes when used directly with reflection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change default app.config at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150644/change-default-app-config-at-runtime)

Comment: @yms: not quite, since the service also will have its own configuration file, but may need to read from several into its "configuration-container"

Comment: May be you can load the dlls in a separate Appdomain and use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.configurationfile.aspx

Comment: Thanks Amit, that was a useful suggestion for some further research

Comment: I was going to suggest the same as Amit, then I found that other question that I thought was dealing with the same problem. A separate AppDomain also has its own inconveniences, but it's worth a try.

Comment: IMHO separate Appdomain may be better suited in this case as the code to be invoked is external. Failure of that code should not bring the whole service down. But if you don't want to go down that way, the post that @yms points to (though it is quite hackish and may stop working if internal implementation gets changed in a future .net version) can still be useful for you. 
You may use the accepted solution like 

// the default app.config is used.
using(AppConfig.Change(tempFileName))
{
    // the app.config in tempFileName is used while inside using
 //invoke the external method
}

Comment: A .dll library can't have its own app.config file unless it uses its own code to locate and read the file. Use ILSpy or another reflector utility to find how exactly does it read the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new AppDomain to invoke your external application.

Define an interface to materialize you external appliation usage.

Create a class derived from MarshallByRefObject and marked as serializable and implement call to external application.

Define an AppDomain without the adequat setting (configuration file, etc)

CreateInstanceAndUnwrap implementation as you interface and call it.