# how to read c# config file of your program with external startup program

Tags: c#, vsto, config, configurationmanager

I have a project that adds some functionality to Excel. The way it is setup right now, includes adding "C:.....\Excel.exe" as the start action (Under Debug>Start Action>Start external program)

Now I have a config file (app.config), but when I use ConfigurationManager to read the config items, it reads the C:...\Excel.exe.config file instead of Myapplication.exe.config  (or app.config)

Is there a way of making it read my application.exe.config? I've tried ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration() method but it seems that the config items are not enumerable using this method

Comment: Is this an Excel add-in?

Comment: Hey, yes it's an excel add-in

Comment: Then see [Excel Add-In not loading app.config with service reference config information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13199432/excel-add-in-not-loading-app-config-with-service-reference-config-information).

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = "pathToConfigFile" }, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```