# Loading app.config into the AppDomain

Tags: powershell, appdomain

I can't get the App.Config file to load into the App Domain.

I'm using

```
[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", $config_path)
```

from [Powershell Calling .NET Assembly that uses App.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835862/powershell-calling-net-assembly-that-uses-app-config) but the App.Config file is still not loaded.

I've also tried resetting the cache as explained in [Using CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE") doesn't work in PowerShell ISE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420545/using-currentdomain-setdataapp-config-file-doesnt-work-in-powershell-ise) .

Here is my test script:

```
$configFile = "{ActualPhysicalPath}\App.Config"
gc $configFile

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Configuration
[Configuration.ConfigurationManager].GetField("s_initState", "NonPublic, Static").SetValue($null, 0)
[Configuration.ConfigurationManager].GetField("s_configSystem", "NonPublic, Static").SetValue($null, $null)
([Configuration.ConfigurationManager].Assembly.GetTypes() | where {$_.FullName -eq "System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths"})[0].GetField("s_current", "NonPublic, Static").SetValue($null, $null)

[Configuration.ConfigurationManager]::ConnectionStrings[0].Name
[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", $null)
[Configuration.ConfigurationManager]::ConnectionStrings[0].Name
[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", $configFile)
[Configuration.ConfigurationManager]::ConnectionStrings[0].Name
```

I'm always getting the connection strings stored in machine.config, rather than those in the App.config.

How can I get my specific App.Config file loaded in the app domain?

Comment: Have you tried using ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration Method ?

Comment: I just tried it and it's still not working

Comment: I misunderstood the question. Sorry. Can't you rename the config file to YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME.exe.config and copy it to the application folder? This should work. The application will load that file.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try moving your *SetData* statement before the *GetField* statement.

With PowerShell 5.0 on Windows 10, the guidance provided by [the link you reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420545/using-currentdomain-setdataapp-config-file-doesnt-work-in-powershell-ise) seems to work: I'm able to retrieve both *AppSettings* and *ConnectionStrings*.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Configuration

# Set this to the full path of your App.config
$configPath = "C:\Full\Path\To\App.config"

[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", $configPath)
[Configuration.ConfigurationManager].GetField("s_initState", "NonPublic, Static").SetValue($null, 0)
[Configuration.ConfigurationManager].GetField("s_configSystem", "NonPublic, Static").SetValue($null, $null)
([Configuration.ConfigurationManager].Assembly.GetTypes() | where {$_.FullName -eq "System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths"})[0].GetField("s_current", "NonPublic, Static").SetValue($null, $null)

[System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager]::AppSettings
[System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager]::ConnectionStrings
```

Comment: I do not have a working workspace to test this, but if someone can confirm that this works I will give you the answer. Thanks for spending time on that really old question

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the solution presented here: [Change default app.config at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150644/change-default-app-config-at-runtime)

It appears to describe some sort of cache, and that more work has to be done to ensure the loaded data is read.

Th important part of the first answer is: "There exists a class ClientConfigPaths that caches the paths. So, even after changing the path with SetData, it is not re-read, because there already exist cached values. The solution is to remove these, too"