# How to use a specific app config file

Tags: c#, app-config

The below code does not work. It does not get the app settings from the `TestApp.Config` file. Do you know why? And how can I fix it?

```
  public void GetConfig()
  {
     AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", @"C:\dev\VS\ProofOfConcept\ProofOfConcept\TestApp.config");
     var a = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
  }
```

Comment: Try this answer -- it worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6151688/67038  I ended up adapting the code a bit, and wrote an extension method for ApplicationSettingsBase

Comment: The most obvious thing I see is you never load the document.  You just set the location of the file which isn't where it would be in a real situation anyways.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change default app.config at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150644/change-default-app-config-at-runtime)

Answer (score 6):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150644/change-default-app-config-at-runtime) might help:

In the solution posted here there is a method `ResetConfigurationMechanism()` that you should call after you call `CurrentDomain.SetData(...);`.

```
private static void ResetConfigMechanism()
{
   typeof(ConfigurationManager)
   .GetField("s_initState", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)                                                                                   
   .SetValue(null, 0);

   typeof(ConfigurationManager)
   .GetField("s_configSystem", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
   .SetValue(null, null);

   typeof(ConfigurationManager)
   .Assembly.GetTypes()
   .Where(x => x.FullName == 
      "System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths")
   .First()
   .GetField("s_current", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
   .SetValue(null, null);
}
```