# opening configuration file from AppDomain

Tags: c#, .net

Consider the following:

- A windows service with a config file and the setting Engine.Url
- The service loads an assembly into its own AppDomain
- Code in the the assembly needs the setting Engine.Url

  string s = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Engine.Url"]

does not work, s will be null.

Then I tried

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
string engineUrl = config.AppSettings["Engine.Url"];
```

this doesnt compile with the error:
`'System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement.this[System.Configuration.ConfigurationProperty]'` is inaccessible due to its protection level

Is there any way to get to the standard config file from within an AppDomain?

edit:

This doesn't work either, engineUrl will be null:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
KeyValueConfigurationElement engineUrl = config.AppSettings.Settings["Engine.Url"];
```

Comment: Have a look at the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150644/change-default-app-config-at-runtime). It is a bit more work, but it will allow you to load the service's config file at runtime so that the assembly can access its configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: Yes, but it's wonky.

You have a couple options. You can set, I believe, the `ConfigurationFile` property of an `AppDomainSetup` object used when creating your AppDomain.

You can call `AppDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", path_to_file)` (see [the related MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37z40s1c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

Comment: this doesn't work everywhere...there's tons of places that cache the loaded the configuration...including ConfigurationManager internal. See ResetConfigurationMechanism (which still doesn't work globally)

Comment: Yeah, exactly why I said it's wonky. I guess I could have expanded upon that a bit.