# Using app.config to determine a common config file

Tags: windows-services, app-config

I am doing a windows service, using app.config, where there is a section to retrieve common configuration in another file. Using

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", "filepath\\file");
```

works for me, but using

```
string appconfig = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CommonAppSetting"];
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", appconfig);
```

does not. It gets from the app.config of the windows service instead of the common configuration.

Anything I did wrong, or is there other better ways of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset some variables (ClientConfigPaths) in the `ConfigurationManager` in order for it to refresh its values. These can be seen in the following accepted answer (complete with code for doing this legwork).

[Change default app.config at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150644/change-default-app-config-at-runtime/6151688#6151688)