# How to reference / use assemblies within T4 file that must exist locally?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-assembly, t4

I'm trying to set up a T4 file that should create a new DBContext object. The configuration is loaded from a .config File.

I'm using a DevartProvider instead of the default SqlServerProvider, which is normally referenced with CopyLocal set to True within a project.

Within the T4 template file im using

```
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)\SomePath\Devart.Data.PostgreSql.Entity.dll" #>
```

but when creating the DBContext I get an Exception because the dll is not found:

```
Additional information: The Entity Framework provider type 'Devart.Data.PostgreSql.Entity.PgSqlEntityProviderServices, Devart.Data.PostgreSql.Entity' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Devart.Data.PostgreSql' could not be loaded Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application.
```

I could copy the DLL to the IDE  folder where the T4 gets executed (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE), but since this setup should run on multiple machines this workaround would be unacceptable.

How can I make this assembly available during T4 execution?

Comment: Consider register the assembly to GAC, and then reference it?

Comment: Well registering within the GAC would also lead to additional steps to make this work which have to be replicated on each development machine which I try to avoid. There is also another DLL that must be referenced (where the DatabaseInitializer is defined) so a code based solution within the T4 would be my preferred choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the *AppDomain.AssemblyResolve* delegate (see [How to add folder to assembly search path at runtime in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373100/how-to-add-folder-to-assembly-search-path-at-runtime-in-net)). For complettenes of the following code, [Change default app.config at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150644/change-default-app-config-at-runtime) should also be mentioned:

```
AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
currentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
    string lookupPath = @"PathToTheDllFolder";

    var assemblyname = new AssemblyName(eventArgs.Name).Name;
    var assemblyFileName = Path.Combine(lookupPath, assemblyname + ".dll");
    var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyFileName);

    return assembly;
};

AppConfig.Change(@"PathToConfig.config");

var entities = new MyEntities();
```