# Why Web.Config file is missing in MVC 6 templates, how to set to connection string?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Web config file is missing in Visual studio 2015 MVC 6 templates. How is the connection string set in an application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I provide settings that can be accessed through ConfigurationManager in asp.net 5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29608417/how-can-i-provide-settings-that-can-be-accessed-through-configurationmanager-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ASP.NET 5, the old web.config is no longer used; you will not be able to use `ConfigurationManager` as in previous versions. You can now use JSON, XML, INI, environment variables, or even roll your own configuration source.

- [Documentation on the basics of the new Configuration model](http://whereslou.com/2014/05/23/asp-net-vnext-moving-parts-iconfiguration/)
- [Source Code for the new Configuration model](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration)