# Forcing exe to use web.config

Tags: c#

I have a web application where I need to launch a console application or exe using ProcessStartInfo class like this -

```
var app = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = @"C:\Projects\...\App.exe"
        };
Process.Start(app);
```

My understanding is that this exe would use the default App.exe.config (Correct me if I am wrong!). I want the web application to use the settings available in web.config instead. Please advise.

Comment: Seems like the simplest method is just to copy the settings to the app.config - there's not a simple way to force an app to use a different config file.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters to your .exe as part of the ProcessStartInfo. Or you can perhaps pass it a path to a config file to load as a parameter. Or the path to the web.config could be a setting in your App.exe.config. And it your app then looks up settings values from there.

Comment: Hi Mano.....I was thinking on the lines of the last point you have mentioned...."path to the web.config could be a setting in your App.exe.config"...

I came across this that can be included in the App.exe.config file- 
<configuration>
    <appSettings file="C:\Projects\....\Web.config">       
    </appSettings>
</configuration>

Is this what you were referring to? If yes, is there anything more I need to add?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify config file directory in your executable code. Take a look at [that link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150644/change-default-app-config-at-runtime/6151688#6151688).