# Is there any way to initialize the web.config in C# interactive?

Tags: c#, interactive

I have a ASP.NET MVC project which I am currently working on. I want to try some code in C# interactive, I click on "Initialize interactive with project." I can see the variables, classes and other thing in c# interactive.

Now one thing is broken is static variable that is defined through web.config is throwing exception.

If I paste the code (in interactive window) that is using web.config variable is not working. Anyway to fix this issue.

I check the answer by SeM and I check the appsettings it's have nothing  [image]

update 2:

I setup the code on github with reading appsettings as given in answer, still didn't work, code is here https://github.com/anirugu/CsharpInteractiveTesting

Comment: What prevents you to define your static variable inside the code? Also, what exception it throws?

Comment: If I execute the code, it's saying "The type initializer for 'abc.Globals' threw an exception."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, if you add your setting into config file

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Test" value="Test"/>
</appSettings>
```

and try to read it by `ConfigurationManager`, it will throw exception of missing reference or

> The name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the current context

In C# interactive window you can reference assemblies with keyword `#r`

```
#r "System.Configuration"
```

and then you can get your value:

```
#r "System.Configuration"
var settings = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(@"bin\Debug\YourAppName.dll"); //You can use .exe files too
Console.WriteLine(settings.AppSettings.Settings["Test"].Value);
```

Also! You can add project's all references by **right click to your project -> Initialize Interactive with Projcet** and VS will do all for you.

### Update

For [your example](https://github.com/anirugu/CsharpInteractiveTesting):

```
using System.Configuration;
var settings = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(@"D:\TestProjects\CsharpInteractiveTesting-master\CsharpInteractiveTesting-master\CsharpInteractiveTesting\bin\Debug\CsharpInteractiveTesting.exe");
Console.WriteLine(settings.AppSettings.Settings["foo"].Value);
```

Comment: In ASP.NET MVC 5 I tried initializing the interactive, When I am reading the value it's throwing an exception "The type initializer for 'abc.Globals' threw an exception."

Comment: Please check the `InnerException` property of the `TypeInitializationException`, it will tell more about your exception.

Comment: I update the question with an image, It looks like nothing has been initialized from web.config Is there anyway to get those value in c# interactive or I am missing a part to get this thing done.

Comment: @Adrian please post text, not image.

Comment: @Adrian I update the question with github link, still not working.

Comment: @Adrian I've updated the answer, please try this method too.

Comment: It's inaccessible due to protection level. I will try it soon. give me sometime. thanks for help

Answer (score 5):

C# interactive itself runs as a separate application with separate application configuration file. If you run this in C# interactive:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile
```

You will see something like:

```
"<path to VS>\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\ManagedLanguages\\VBCSharp\\InteractiveComponents\\InteractiveHost.exe.Config"
```

So that's the config file being used. Of course it does not contain your variables, so code trying to do `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["foo"].ToString()` fails.

Usual way to set config file at runtime is:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", fullPathToYourConfig);
```

However, this should be done *before* any access to configuration file. When first access is made - file is being cached and subsequent changes to path will have no effect. Unfortunately, before giving you access to executing commands, C# interactive already works with that file.

There are various hacks with reflection to reset that cache. For example (copied verbatim from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6150644/5311735)):

```
public static void ChangeConfigTo(string path)
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", path);
    typeof(ConfigurationManager)
        .GetField("s_initState", BindingFlags.NonPublic |
            BindingFlags.Static)
        .SetValue(null, 0);

    typeof(ConfigurationManager)
        .GetField("s_configSystem", BindingFlags.NonPublic |
            BindingFlags.Static)
        .SetValue(null, null);

    typeof(ConfigurationManager)
        .Assembly.GetTypes()
        .Where(x => x.FullName ==
            "System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths")
        .First()
        .GetField("s_current", BindingFlags.NonPublic |
            BindingFlags.Static)
        .SetValue(null, null);
}
```

With all that in mind, if you put that function in `Program` class in your sample on github and do this in C# interactive:

```
Program.ChangeConfigTo(Path.GetFullPath("app.config"));
```

Your code will work as you expect. You can put this hack in separate script (`.csx`) file and load it with "#load" if necessary.